# how do i identify that a cosmos db container is empty and needs to be seeded?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am via EF core accessing my cosmos db database.

I have via Ef core overriden the OnModelCreating to check whether the underlying database and container exists. but I am not sure How I should check whether it contains any data?

EfCore does not seem to have any count, or no way to check whether the underlying db is empty?

This what I have tried so far

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var client = Database.GetCosmosClient();
        var dbResponse = client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync("Db").Result.StatusCode;
        ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties("forms", "/forms");
        var database = client.GetDatabase("Db");
        var containerResponse = database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerProperties).Result.StatusCode;

        //Database or container was recently created, hence reseed 
        if (dbResponse == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created
            || containerResponse == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Model created but need seeding");
    return;
        }

        var container = database.GetContainer("forms");
    //How to check data is in the container?            

    }
```

Based on the answer provided by @Svyatoslav Danyli i created two methods.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;

namespace FormsRetriever
{
    public static class SeedingTools
    {
        public static void CheckDatabase(DbContext dbContext)
        {
            dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
            var client = dbContext.Database.GetCosmosClient();
            SeedData(dbContext);

        }

        private static void SeedData(DbContext dbContext)
        {

            bool a = dbContext.Set<Forms>().Any();
        }
    }
}
```

Which I call in the startup.

which in return gives me this error

```
A host error has occurred during startup operation '50913447-b407-41a1-95bd-68918f9d3d4b'.
[2022-07-04T11:04:53.059Z] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Forms>()
[2022-07-04T11:04:53.059Z]     .Any()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Comment: In `OnModelCreating` you cannot use `EF Core` to query data. This method only for configuring/initialization. I would suggest to create sperate method and check it in Startup.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv how do you suggest to check it without EF core, I am accessing the db solely through ef core, so I don't see a method which enables me to check this in startup?

Comment: Which kind of Application do you have?

Comment: its an .net azure function app

Comment: So every function can seed data concurrently? Don't you think it is a bad design? It should be separate tool which applies migrations and seeds data.

Comment: The purpose of the function app, is to feed new data to the database, when somebody request it via an http endpoint. 

The seeding is for when I start the app, and there is no content in the database.

the remote endpoint which the data is fetched from include an timestamp, which allow me to fetch data from a certain date.

Comment: "The seeding is for when I start the app, and there is no content in the database" Imagine situation when two functions are executed by Azure on the same time. Who should win?

Comment: I assume the situation is still the same, if datbase already have data in there, then we don't seed, if no then seed. 

Ofcourse there is the sitation in which both instances ask the database whether the database have any data in it , to prevent that I guess we can lock the database to ensure that only one instance have access to it in case it need to be seeded.

Comment: Well, move `OnModelCreating`  check code to some kind of method `CheckDataIntegrity(DbContext)` and execute it in function body.

Comment: what about the data check?
I only check existense of database and container now, and assume that seeding is needed if both was just created.

I still don't have an indication for whether I need to seed or not.

Comment: In my current case only one instance is needed. 
and will be limited to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move check code to appropriate function and execute when EF Core is properly configured:

```cs
public static class DatabaseTools
{
    public static void CheckDatabase(DbContext context)
    {
        // EF Core will create database and containters
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        // Cosmos provider do not supports Any
        if (dbContext.Set<Form>().FirstOrDefault() == null)
        {
            // seed data
            context.Set<Form>().AddRange(
                new []
                {
                    new Form{},
                    new Form{},
                    new Form{},
                }
            );

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no sure why this should  be in startup, and not in `OnModelCreating`?

Comment: In `OnModelCreating` Model configuration is not finished. If Model is unknown - EF Core can do almost nothing.

Comment: Ahh true, and then you just call in the startup by             using var context = new 
ModelContext();
CheckDatabase(context)
Cause that returns an error..

Comment: I tried the any method, but see, to have issues
 `   .Any()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, `

Comment: Which issues? Update question with exception details and callstack.

Comment: I adjusted the question, with the issue I run into .

Comment: Try `bool a = dbContext.Set<Forms>().FirstOrDefault() != null;`